# Reading vs studying?

Tags: united-kingdom, terminology

In the UK students often say they are "studying" a topic (e.g., "I am studying computer science at University of X") but once in a while I also hear students say they are "reading" a topic (e.g., "I am reading sociology"). The latter I've only heard said in the context of social sciences.

Is there a difference between reading and studying a topic?

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference.

If you wanted to use the word "reading", the proper usage would be "I am reading for a degree in X." This is not limited to social sciences; it would apply to any degree.

However, this has become something of an old-fashioned expression; it's far more common to say that you are "studying X" or "doing a degree in X".

Source: I am a student in the UK.